# Is use of allocator::rebind required by C++ standard?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

I thought containers have to rebind whatever allocator they are given into an allocator that works, but in STL that ships with LLVM (part of libc++, I guess), this doesn't seem to be the case. Is this a bug in LLVM, or does the standard not require rebinding?

The following snippet works as expected with GCC's STL. It fails with STL that comes with clang 3.3 (from MacPorts, on a Mac). It compiles fine with clang on Linux, but I think that one uses the same STL as GCC.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char, std::allocator<int> >  c;
    c.push_back(5);
}
```

The error is

```
clang++ test-rebind.cpp 
In file included from test-rebind.cpp:1:
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.3/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:505:5: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template '__static_assert_test<false>'
    static_assert((is_same<typename allocator_type::value_type, value_type>::value),
    ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.3/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:412:35: note: expanded from macro 'static_assert'
    typedef __static_assert_check<sizeof(__static_assert_test<(__b)>)> \
                                  ^
test-rebind.cpp:5:46: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::vector<char, std::__1::allocator<int> >' requested here
    std::vector<char, std::allocator<int> >  c;
                                             ^
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.3/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:408:24: note: template is declared here
template <bool> struct __static_assert_test;
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: _Hm, the comment this was a response to has been deleted, but I'll leave the response, just in case._ Well, rebinding the allocator fixes the problem. I thought the container should do it automatically inside (that's how GCC's STL does it). My manual fix for this is to rebind all (custom) allocators for each container. It's tedious, but it works.

Comment: The comment was deleted because I noticed that I had misread your code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

23.2.1 [container.requirements.general]/7:

> All other constructors for these container types take an `Allocator&` argument (17.6.3.5), an allocator whose value type is the same as the container’s value type.

So your code is invalid.

The above is a rather obscure place to find this, though. We can do better. Table 99 (allocator-aware container requirements) requires in its first row that the container has an `allocator_type` nested type, whose `value_type` is identical to the container's. And the synopsis for `vector` (and the other containers) defines `allocator_type` thus:

```
typedef Allocator allocator_type;
```

In other words, the `Allocator` parameter you supply is responsible for fulfilling the requirement.

Comment: Meaning GCC used to be too lenient, and LLVM's STL is correctly enforcing the rule?

Comment: Correct, libstdc++ is too lenient, while libc++ contains an explicit static assertion that the requirement is adhered to.

Comment: libstdc++ checks the requirement with concept checks enabled, but not otherwise

Answer (score 3):

> I thought containers have to rebind whatever allocator they are given into an allocator that works

I can’t find that requirement anywhere. Rather, `rebind` is used if the container needs to allocate *something other than `value_type`*. Consider a typical, simplified `list` implementation:

```
template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>>
class list {
    struct node {
        T value;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
    };
    using allocator = typename A::template rebind<node>::other;
};
```

Here we need to use `rebind` because the `list` doesn’t allocate `T`s; it allocates `list<T>::node`s.

Comment: But in libc++, std::allocator does not have a `rebind` member.  So how is one supposed to do this?

Comment: @ChrisDodd It depends on the version of C++ you are using. C++20 removed `rebind`. I have no idea what you are supposed to do now since I have never used C++17 in production, I just know that the allocation interface was completely reworked since `std::allocator` was, frankly, not really usable beforehand. The solution is probably to use `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` instead.